# mruby issue with require and require_relative

Tags: mruby

I am trying my hand on with mRuby. I compiled the mRuby source locally.  I tried this simple example:

### inc.rb

```
def test(a, b)
    print "Inside the include->test(..)"
    return a+b
end
```

### test1.rb

```
require_relative 'inc.rb'

def helloworld(var1)
    print 'hello world ' + var1 + ". Test number = " + test(4, 5)

end

helloworld('test')
```

### test2.rb

```
require 'inc.rb'

def helloworld(var1)
    print 'hello world ' + var1 + ". Test number = " + test(4, 5)

end

helloworld('test')
```

I executed both the test programs using mruby.
mruby.exe test1.rb
mruby.exe test2.rb

In both the cases I get the error:

```
"undefined method 'require_relative' for main (NoMethodError)"

"undefined method 'require' for main (NoMethodError)"
```

Does mRuby not support 'require'?

Answer (score 2):

mruby doesn't have require functionality.
But you can use mruby-require mgem.
https://github.com/mattn/mruby-require
If you build mruby with mruby-require, then you can use require. require_relative is not supported.

Comment: how do I build mruby with mruby-require?

Comment: Just look "install by mrbgems" section of previous link.

Comment: I got the the code to compile, thank you :). Now I have another issue. I am getting this error: NoMethodError: undefined method 'puts' for main  Can you help me? This is the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140687/mruby-require-error-nomethoderror-undefined-method-puts-for-main