# mruby-require error: NoMethodError: undefined method 'puts' for main

Tags: mruby

I managed to compile the mruby code adding the mrubygem - mruby-require from  https://github.com/mattn/mruby-require

However when I try to call the require './' I get an error. Below is my code:

### inc.rb

```
def test(a, b)
    print "Inside the include->test(..)"
    return a+b
end
```

### test1.rb

```
require 'inc.rb'

def helloworld(var1)
    print 'hello world ' + var1 + ". Test number = " + test(4, 5)

end

helloworld('test')
```

When I execute test1.rb I get this error from mruby:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'puts' for main
```

After some analysis I found out the 'puts' is not working with mruby. Infact after adding mruby-require gem, no ruby code gets execute. Do I need to add any dependency with mruby-require?

Can someone help me please?

Update: Pasting the content of build_config.rb as requested. I have removed the lines which are commented.

### build_config.rb

```
MRuby::Build.new do |conf|

  if ENV['VisualStudioVersion'] || ENV['VSINSTALLDIR']
    toolchain :visualcpp
  else
    toolchain :gcc
  end

  enable_debug

  # adding the mruby-require library
  conf.gem 'mrbgems/mruby-require'

  conf.gembox 'default'


end

MRuby::Build.new('host-debug') do |conf|

  if ENV['VisualStudioVersion'] || ENV['VSINSTALLDIR']
    toolchain :visualcpp
  else
    toolchain :gcc
  end

  enable_debug

  conf.gembox 'default'


  conf.cc.defines = %w(ENABLE_DEBUG)


  conf.gem :core => "mruby-bin-debugger"


end
```

Comment: @cremno thanks. This is the only line I added in the build_config.rb conf.gem 'mrbgems/mruby-require' . Let me know if you want me to paste the complete content of build_config.rb, will paste it in the Question part.

Comment: @cremno, I have updated the Question, pasted the content of `build_config.rb`. I have removed the commented lines to make the content readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following quote is from its [`README.md`](https://github.com/mattn/mruby-require/blob/46558881e5f44e12d506d2cc9e148598835d6e8d/README.md#requiring-additional-mrbgems):

> When mruby-require is being used, additional mrbgems that appear *after* mruby-require in build_config.rb must be required to be used.

This is from your `build_config.rb`:

```
  conf.gem 'mrbgems/mruby-require'

  conf.gembox 'default'
```

[The `default` gembox contains `mruby-print`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/ff49cf95fca2d1648f05dd636c8f8516c8edc815/mrbgems/default.gembox#L5-L6). So either require `mruby-print` or preferably swap the lines to make it a built-in gem (the default behavior without `mruby-require`).